# Where docker volumes are located?

Tags: docker, macos

Need to know where docker volumes are located when using the docker machine on macOS.
The installation is using boot2docker, so the VM works behind.

Example:

```
docker volume create test-data
```

docker inspect shows a path, but where can I find the specific (physical) location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s inside the virtual machine and isn’t directly accessible from the host.

Debug-level commands like `docker volume inspect` will give you a path, but they really are only for emergency debugging and not for routine use.  If you have a way to get a shell in the VM you can see that path, but you really shouldn’t be directly accessing files there, and you shouldn’t be routinely `docker inspect`ing anything.

Answer (score 7):

**macOS** use a **virtual machine** it's different to linux where you can access to volumes from /var/lib/docker/volumes.
For macOS you should connect to a VM to find your volumes.

If you use persistent data volumes in Docker, and you want to access them with command-line.

If your docker host is Linux, that’s not a problem; you can find Docker volumes by **/var/lib/docker/volumes** path.

However, that’s not the case when you use Docker for Mac. 
Try to cd /var/lib/docker/volumes from your MacOS terminal, you ‘ll get nothing.

You see, your Mac machine isn’t a real Docker host. Docker for Mac runs a virtual machine and hides it from you to make things simple.

So, to access persistent volumes created by Docker for Mac, you need to connect on that VM.

In order to accomplish this, we need to use a serial terminal on Mac. There’s a terminal application called “screen” that’s going to help us.

We need to “screen into” the Docker driver by executing a command:

screen
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty

1. screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
2. You should see a blank screen, just press Enter , and after a while, you should see a command line prompt
3. Now you’re inside Docker’s VM and you can cd into volumes dir by typing: cd /var/lib/docker/volumes

Profit, you got there!

If you need to transfer files from your MacOS host into Docker host you can refer to [File Sharing](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: as of july 2022, with docker desktop for macos, there is no `tty` program anywhere inside `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/`. And the File Sharing link links to a page that does not deal with file sharing...

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed docker using snap then volumes are located at:

```
/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/
```

Answer (score -2):

Normally, if you want to "know" where a volume lives, you would want to map a volume to the local filesystem. When you create a named volume you are just allocating "shared" storage. However, if your really need to know, run this command:

```
docker volume inspect test-data
```

Comment: This is not the question.

Answer (score -2):

location of volumes when using docker official install

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/
```