# MongoDB running in docker container is not exiting correctly on windows

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:-

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    volumes:
      - c:\dev\mongodb-data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=memory-game
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=appuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  redis-server:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

When I run it the first time, it is fine, but when I run it the second time, I get an error about there being a WiredTiger error.

```
C:\dev\myprojects\memorygame>docker-compose --env-file ./.env up
Starting mongodb                   ... done
Starting memorygame_redis-server_1 ... done
Attaching to mongodb, memorygame_redis-server_1
redis-server_1  | 1:C 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.831 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-server_1  | 1:C 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.831 # Redis version=6.0.10, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-server_1  | 1:C 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.831 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 # Server initialized
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.10
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 * RDB age 6 seconds
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 * RDB memory usage when created 0.77 Mb
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis-server_1  | 1:M 01 Mar 2021 00:05:55.832 * Ready to accept connections
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.878+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.880+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.881+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.882+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"551f6443f1a3"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.882+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.4","gitVersion":"8db30a63db1a9d84bdcad0c83369623f708e0397","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.882+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.882+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.885+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:55.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=482M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.026+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1614557156:26674][1:0x7fb86cb91ac0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.043+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1614557156:43001][1:0x7fb86cb91ac0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.057+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1614557156:57244][1:0x7fb86cb91ac0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.059+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.059+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.059+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1123}}
mongodb         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-03-01T00:05:56.059+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
mongodb exited with code 14
```

If I delete all the data, I can run it again. I tried deleting the WiredTiger.lock file and mongodb.lock file. Deleting both files seems to have no effect. Can someone please clarify what the lock file files are about and let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello, use VOLUME instead of "c:\dev\mongodb-data" maybe it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Seddick. Can you clarify how I go about doing that in docker compose?

Answer (score 1):

The example clarify how to use volumes instead of c:/...

NB: VOLUMES is in the same level of services  ! hope it helps!

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=memory-game
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=appuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
 redis-server:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
volumes:
    mongodb-data:
```

Comment: Can you please clarify where the data is now stored?

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886883/where-docker-volumes-are-located/56550330#56550330